# Callback Issue with codebird.js Twitter Search

Tags: search, twitter, oauth, callback

I'm having difficulty getting the callback function to work with codebird.js running a tweet search. I get the request response in my log and it appears to be working, but search_callback(result) does not run. Below is the code:

```
var cb = new Codebird();
cb.setConsumerKey("<fill in>","<fill in>");
cb.setToken('<fill in>','<fill in>');  

cb.__call('users/search', {
     'q' : 'reddit',
    'callback' : 'search_callback',
     }
 );

function search_callback (result){
    alert('x');
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax has changed. Here is what I should have done:

```
var cb = new Codebird();
cb.setConsumerKey('<fill-in>','<fill-in>');
cb.setToken('<fill-in>','<fill-in>');  

cb.__call(
'search_tweets',
'q=reddit',
function (reply) {
    alert('x');
    }
 );
```